# How to reset Workflow Actions that weren't run due to a GitHub incident?

Tags: github

GitHub Actions were [unavailable](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/tf9v5jjmq2lg) for some time and PRs created in this time did not trigger any actions. After the functionality was restored the PRs did not pick up the status correctly and don't even have a `Re-run jobs` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close and reopen the PR (make sure you have enough privileges to do that) to trigger the Workflows check.